# Access to entire confusion matrix

Tags: google-cloud-automl

after training an image classification model using AutoML Vision, the "Evaluate" tab gives access to model performance, specifically to the confusion matrix. My dataset has over 100 labels, but the confusion matrix is only displayed as a 10x10 matrix. My questions:

- does the confusion matrix only display the worst performances (above a certain threshold for example) or is this limited to a 10x10 representation regardless of performance?
- Is there a way to access the entire confusion matrix?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind: after reading through the [cloud-vision-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloud-vision-discuss) google group, I found the answer: you can get the entire matrix through the API: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.models.modelEvaluations

Comment: Found out that even the API only returns the 10 first rows any more. Eagerly waiting for a fix by Google...