# Google AutoML - View complete confusion matrix?

Tags: google-vision, google-cloud-automl

Ive been successfully training image classifiers with Google Cloud AutoML, however, when I have a large number of tags the evaluation tab for my model shows an incomplete confusion matrix - ie: only a subset of tags are listed.

How do I, within the UI - view the entire confusion matrix of my model?

Ive seen other S/O q's which haven't been updated / answered for some time:

[Access to entire confusion matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52965044/access-to-entire-confusion-matrix)

- Is this currently possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In the answer you found I can see they got the Confusion Matrix via the API.

As far as I can see, there's no other version for that API, so it should still valid.

Note that [AutoML Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/) is on Beta stage so it might get changed as well as the API.

Comment: The note in that answer is the matrix is incomplete ;) Same as the UI